# getView() parameter passing in android adapter

Tags: android

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
     viewholder holder;
     if(vi==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
         holder=new viewholder();

            holder.tview1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.MXname);
         holder.tview1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){

                    Log.d("Name view Click","in the list");
                    }
                }
         );

            holder.tview2=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.MXtnumber);
            holder.tview2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Log.d("Number view Click","in the list"+position);
                }
                }
          );

           holder.imageview=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.MXdialer);
           holder.imageview.setTag(position);
         holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
            //Integer no = new Integer(0);
                        // get the number to dial and pass to DialNo
                //madapter.this.DialNo();
                    Log.d("Dialer view Click","in the list");
                    }
                }
         );
         vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(viewholder)vi.getTag();


      return vi;


    }
}
}
```

PLease see a draft of getview() adapter code above related to listview/android, When i try using "position" parameter in any of the onclick methods above I get error "**Cannot refer to a non-final variable position inside an inner class defined in a different method"**
The only work around I can do is make it a final variable and then access that final variable in onclick() method. Please suggest if there is any other way of doing this without using final variable. thanks in advance

Comment: you can mark position as final

Comment: as @blackbelt said: `getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

Comment: If you absolutely need to avoid using final, subclass your Adapter and use a class level parameter to save the position each time getView is called (this.pos=position;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to mark the position as final, then set the position as a Tag of the View:

```
holder.tview2.setTag(position);
holder.tview2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Log.d("Number view Click","in the list"+(String)v.getTag());
                }
);
```

Btw: You should not create a new `OnClickListener` for each item of the List. Instead use `holder.tview2.setOnClickListener(this);` and implement `OnClickListener` on your adapter. And that of course for all your `TextView` and `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the tag of each subview that has an OnClickListener to be the position of the parent view in the list. That way in your OnClickListener you can call

```
int pos = (int)view.getTag();
```

Keep in mind you have to set the position each time getView is run, not just during inflation, as the views get recycled so their positions will change.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
@Override 
public View getView(int position,....
```

TO:

```
@Override 
public View getView(final int position,
```